# Android preferences spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-preferences

How can I build something like this? I wanna open a dialog in the Preferences Activity, where the user can change the number with a spinner, when he clicks on the according preference item.

[image: Screenshots from the Android Messaging app's settings. Selecting an item defined by a Preference opens an interface to change the setting.]

I got the screenshot from [Android Developer Tools](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), but I cannot find some example code.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: the widget shown in the screenshot is a "picker" instead of a "spinner"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed a Custom Preference, which can be found [here](https://github.com/vanniktech/VNTNumberPickerPreference).

XML Code:

```
<com.vanniktech.vntnumberpickerpreference.VNTNumberPickerPreference
    android:defaultValue="@integer/font_size_default_value"
    android:key="preference_font_size"
    android:title="@string/font_size"
    app:vnt_maxValue="@integer/font_size_max_value"
    app:vnt_minValue="@integer/font_size_min_value" />
```

Gradle include:

```
compile 'com.vanniktech:vntnumberpickerpreference:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi @Niklas, i'm not able to build project VNTNumberPickerPreference in my eclipse. can you pls help me

Comment: Yes you can't because I am using Gradle, so you either have to use a Gradle Plugin in Eclipse or use Android Studio (which will be supported by Google in the future not like Eclipse)

Comment: How can I use this with Strings?

Comment: @tim687 that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Spinner/picker in the preference's event handler:

```
final EditTextPreference msgLimitPref = (EditTextPreference)
                                 findPreference("prefMsgLimit");
                         msgLimitPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new
                                 OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                                     msgLimitPref.getDialog().dismiss();
                                   //launch spinner/numberpicker/activity/dialog here
                                 return true;
                                 }
                                 });
```