# Number picker preference in API 8

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

i googled lot, i found few sample posts in SO about Number picker but none has given implementation of Number picker from API 8

[Android preferences spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508155/android-preferences-spinner)

The default number picker is available from API 11, but what is the best alternative for that to implement from API 8 onwards?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282337/alternative-to-numberpicker-for-api-8

Comment: Any alternatives which gives look like ICS theme